# NumberFormatter - ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, numberformatter

How do I create a number formatter for formatting large numbers with commas?

For example, 2389378.289 should become 2,389,378.289

Note that there is not always three decimal places, nor is there always a decimal at all. Please use NSNumberFormatter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[fmt setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:NO];
[fmt setFormat:@"#,##0.###"];
NSLog(@"%@",[fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:35.424252]]);
NSLog(@"%@",[fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:21.3]]);
NSLog(@"%@",[fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10392425]]);
```

The format Chuck gave you supports up to 3 decimal places.  If you have a number with less than 3 they just don't show up.  Chuck is also correct that you want to take a look at the Unicode number format guide, it is invaluable for number formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

The format for that would be `@"#,##0.###"`. Take a look at [the Unicode number format guide](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Number_Format_Patterns) for a full explanation of how to construct format strings.

(Also note that this works correctly in locales where commas and dots are reversed, or where other characters are used.)

Comment: Can you show me the full objective-C code using NSNumberFormatter? And note that it is not always 3 decimal places, nor is there even always a decimal at all.